# Office Script - array.splice affects 2 arrays for unknown reasons

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I am currently creating a script to automate populating a calendar. Right now, I'm stuck on this problem where I don't know why but this splice seems to be affecting my 2 arrays...

Here is the section of code where I have my splice :

```
// Remove element from temporary list
console.log('--before', ihListCountry, populatingIhListCountry);  
populatingIhListCountry.splice(j, 1);  
console.log('--after', ihListCountry, populatingIhListCountry);
```

And here is the result in the console :

```
--before  
(11) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …]  
(11) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …]  
--after  
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]  
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]  
--before  
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]  
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
--after  
(9) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]  
(9) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

As you can see from the lenght, both are affected by the splice, anyone knows what the problem is here?

Edit:
Here's the whole function and where I initialize the array :

```
function populateIHListCalendar(
  workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
  currentWorksheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet,
  rangeText: string[],
  targetRange: ExcelScript.Range,
  ihListCountry: socTeam[]
) {
  let populatingIhListCountry: socTeam[] = ihListCountry;
  let availabilityWorksheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];
  let availabilityRange: ExcelScript.Range = availabilityWorksheet.getUsedRange();
  //Loop through each cells
  for (let i: number = 0; i < rangeText.length; i++) {
    let ihAvailability: boolean = false;
    // Refill list if it's empty
    if (populatingIhListCountry.length == 0) {
      populatingIhListCountry = ihListCountry;
    }
    let availabilityColumn: string[][] = availabilityWorksheet.getUsedRange().getColumn(i).getTexts();
    let j: number = 0;
    let whileCycle: number = 0; 
    while(ihAvailability === false) {
      // Here I call a function comparing the IH Title with my Out of Office Calendar, returning true if the IH is available during this time period
      ihAvailability = compareAvailabilityAndIHList(availabilityColumn, populatingIhListCountry, j);
      if (ihAvailability === false) {
        j++;
        if (j === populatingIhListCountry.length && whileCycle === 0) {
          j = 0;
          whileCycle = 1;
        }
        else if (j === populatingIhListCountry.length && whileCycle === 1) {
          populatingIhListCountry = populatingIhListCountry.concat(ihListCountry);
          console.log('First cycle, no available IH in the remaining list available!');
          whileCycle = 2;
        }
        else if (j === populatingIhListCountry.length && whileCycle === 2) {
          console.log('Error! No available IH found!');
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (j === populatingIhListCountry.length && whileCycle === 2) {
      break;
    }

    // Add IH to calendar
    let calendarTable: ExcelScript.Table = currentWorksheet.getTables()[0];

    let columnRange = calendarTable.getColumn(rangeText[i]).getRange().getValues();
    let k: number = 0;
    while (columnRange[k] != undefined && columnRange[k].toString() != "") {
      k++;
    }
    if (calendarTable.getColumn(rangeText[i]).getRange().getCellCount() === j) {
      calendarTable.addRow();
    }
    currentWorksheet.getCell(k, calendarTable.getColumn(rangeText[i]).getIndex()).setValue(populatingIhListCountry[j].Title);

    // Remove element from temporary list
    console.log('--before', ihListCountry, populatingIhListCountry);
    populatingIhListCountry.splice(j, 1);
    console.log('--after', ihListCountry, populatingIhListCountry);
  }

  // IH Calendar is generated
}
```

Comment: It means they are the same array. You have probably *thought* that you copied one array to another, but you just *assigned* the same array reference to the other variable.

Comment: Show us the code where you initialized the array. 
Both are referencing the same thing, in this case for sure.

Comment: I added the code where I initialized the array, hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

The blow code is create a new array, but both variables are SAME array.

```js
let populatingIhListCountry: socTeam[] = ihListCountry;
```

A snippet to show it, both array are changed after the third line.

```js
const originalList: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const copyList: number[] = originalList;
originalList[0] = 99
console.log(originalList)
console.log(copyList)

// Output
// [LOG]: [99, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
// [LOG]: [99, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You have several options to create an independent copy of a list (Array).

```js
// Using the spread operator:
const originalList1: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const copyList1: number[] = [...originalList1];
originalList1[0] = 99
console.log(originalList1)
console.log(copyList1)

// Output
// [LOG]: [99, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
// [LOG]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

// Using the slice() method:
const originalList2: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const copyList2: number[] = originalList2.slice();
originalList2[0] = 99
console.log(originalList1)
console.log(copyList1)

// Output
// [LOG]: [99, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
// [LOG]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```